# COMP SCI 101/JAVA Creating an Array with 1000 Random Integers, then performing a Frequency Count and calculating average

Tags: java

This is a programming assignment I am having some trouble with. I cannot use anything that was not taught to us in class. I believe my code may be redundant (I think I have one too many count-controlled loops).

Here is the question:

Create an application that fills an array with 1,000 random integers, each between 1 and 10. Your program should then perform a frequency count – How many elements are equal to 1, how many are equal to 2, etc. for all 10 possible values. Your program should also calculate the average of the values. Your application should output a neatly formatted summary report to a text file with the summary results, not the entire array.

I believe I have created an array that is filled with 1000 random integers between 1 and 10 properly. When I get to the frequency count part of the problem, I need it to output the exact number of integers equal to 1, equal to 2, and so forth. With my output currently, it is printing every single random value that is equal to 1 instead of the exact number of values equal to 1.

Here is my code: any help would be greatly appreciated.  Also I think I might have one too many count-controlled loops.  Maybe that is my problem?

```
/**
 * This method fills an array with 1,000 random integers, each between 
 * 1 and 10.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] num = new int[1000]; //an array of 1000 integers
    int i; //used as an array index

    for( i= 0; i < 1000; i++)
        num[i] = 1+(int) (Math.random()*((10-1)+1)); 
 //math.Random generates a number between 0 and 1, this method calls for numbers
    //to be between 1 and 10. To make this possible, I need to multiply
    //the math.random by the max-min and add 1 to make sure it generates
    //1,000 random integers between 1 and 10.

    int count1;  //used to count how many integers are equal to 1
    System.out.println ("Integers equal to 1");
    //this loop prints the values in the array
    for(i=0; i<1000; i++)
        if (num[i] == 1)
        {
            i++;
            System.out.println(i + "of the random 1000 integers are equal to 1.");
        }
```

This is the information in my textbook that I am using to create my code.

The variable countEven is first initialized to zero, then, as we iterate the array, we will increment the count for each even Fibonacci number. To test for even numbers, we will use the Java’s remaindering operation (%), which returns the remainder of an integer division operation. If the remainder is zero when we divide by two, then the number is an even number.

```
int[] fib = {0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34} // an array initialized with Fibonacci numbers
int i;// used as an array index
int countEven; used to count how many of the first 10 Fibonacci numbers are even
System.out.println(“Even Fibonacci numbers” );
// this loop prints the values in the array
for( i= 0; i < fib.length; i++)
if (fib[i] % 2 == 0)
{
count++;
System.out.println( fib[i] + “ is even”);
}
system.out.println ( count + “ of the first 10 Fibonacci numbers are even”);
```

The output looks like this:
Even Fibonacci numbers
0 is even
2 is even
8 is even
34 is even
4 of the first 10 Fibonacci numbers are even.

Comment: Use another array to keep track of the frequencies of each of the integers from `1..10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i=0; i<1000; i++)
        if (num[i] == 1)
        {
            i++;
            System.out.println(i + "of the random 1000 integers are equal to 1.");
        }
```

Change the code above to:

```
for(i=0; i<1000; i++)
        if (num[i] == 1)
        {
            count1++;
        }
System.out.println(count1 + "of the random 1000 integers are equal to 1.");
```

See if you can get what you want.

Comment: Thank you. But this did not output as a concise statement showing the exact number of variables that are equal to 1. It presented a list of variables equal to 1.

Comment: @user2803066 Have you tried my code? It seems to work for me :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of issues. In the block

```
if ( num[i] == 1 ) {
    i++;
    System.out.println(i + "of the random 1000 integers are equal to 1.");    
}
```

You are incrementing `i`, not `count1`

Also, you are printing out the results each time `if ( num[i] == 1 )` is true, not just once at the end.

Comment: Jeff, thank you. I added the information from my textbook which I am using the write my frequency counter. From your information, I am having trouble figuring out how to fix my code.